# How is CPython implemented?

Tags: python, cpython

So I lately came across an explanation for Python's interpreter and compiler (CPython specifically).

Please correct me if I'm wrong. I just want to be sure I understand these specific concepts.

So CPython gets both compiled (to bytecode) and then interpreted (in the PVM)?
And what does the PVM do exactly? Does it read the bytecode line by line, and translate each one to binary instructions that can be executed on a specific computer?
Does this mean that a computer based on an Intel processor needs a different PVM from an AMD-based computer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, CPython is compiled to bytecode which is then executed by the virtual machine.
2. The virtual machine executes instructions one-by-one. It's written in C (but you can write it in another language) and looks like a huge `if/else` statement like "if the current instruction is this, do this; if the instruction is this, do another thing", and so on. Instructions aren't translated to binary - that's why it's called an *interpreter*.

   1. You can find the list of instructions here: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/dis.html#python-bytecode-instructions
   2. The implementation of the VM is available here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f71a69aa9209cf67cc1060051b147d6afa379bba/Python/ceval.c#L1718
3. Bytecode doesn't have a concept of "line": it's just a stream of bytes. The interpreter can read one byte at a time and use another `if/else` statement to decide what instruction it's looking at. For example:

   ```
   curr_byte = read_byte()
   if curr_byte == 0x00:
      # Parse instruction with no arguments
      curr_instruction = DO_THING_A;
      args = NULL;
   elif curr_byte == 0x01:
      another_byte = read_byte()
      if another_byte == 0x00:
         # Parse a two-byte instruction
         curr_instruction = DO_THING_B;
         args = NULL;
      else:
         # Parse a one-byte instruction
         # with one argument
         curr_instruction = DO_THING_C;
         args = another_byte >> 1; # or whatever
   elif curr_byte == ...:
      ... # go on and on and on
   ```
4. The entire point of bytecode is that it can be executed by *another program* (the interpreter, or virtual machine) on almost any hardware. For example, in order to get CPython running on new hardware, you'll need a C toolchain (compiler, linker, assembler etc) for this hardware and a bunch of functions that Python can call to do low-level stuff (allocate memory, output text, do networking etc). Once you have that, write C code that can execute the bytecode - and that's it.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for you answer.
So just to see that I understand... basically every different type of hardware also uses different instruction.
So when CPython gets compiled, it's generic and used for the PVM.
But, the for each type of hardware, the PVM is written differently, to match this type of hardware.
Please correct me if I got something wrong.

Comment: Basically yes, different hardware (technically, different instruction set architectures) have different sets of instructions. However, you as a user don't need to care about this too much because this is being taken care of by developers of LLVM, GCC and other assemblers/compilers